# UIButton at bottom of UIScrollView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

My UI structure goes like this:

```
- View
  - Scroll View
    - Container View
      - Dynamically added UI element
      - Dynamically added UI element
      - Dynamically added UI element
      - ....
      - UIButton
```

After adding all the UI elements (including the UIButton with an UITapGestureRecognizer) and updating the UIScrollView size with following method...

```
func updateScrollViewSize() {
    var contentRect = CGRect.zero
    for view in containerView.subviews {
        contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
    }
    contentRect.size = CGSize(width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: contentRect.height + TRAILING_SCROLLVIEW_SPACE)
    scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
}
```

...I noticed that it will only work **if I add a UIButton at the top of the view - the ones I only reach by scrolling (e.g. the one at the bottom) do not.**

Well, I thought, so the button gets created **outside of the container views' frame**, thus I added the following line to my `updateScrollViewSize` method.

```
containerView.frame.size = contentRect.size
```

Sadly, this did not solve my problem.

I tried finding a solution for quite some time now, but none could help me out. I'm still 99% sure that it has something to do with my Container Views' frame, but I simply can`t figure out how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try setting the -clipsBounds of the container view to true/yes. Is the button still visible?

Comment: set contentSize of scrollView height = lastly added ui component's y pos + height + 10 or accordingly.

Comment: @isaac: It is not. I debugged it using `print containerView.frame.bounds`, and the height changed accordingly to the content. Is this the wrong property I am accessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `layoutIfNeeded()` on your top view after creating your subviews if using any constraints.
make sure the scrollView's `contentSize` matches your `containerView.frame` (not `.bounds`, since this will not tell you if for instance your frame y-position is below zero.